# Which All for One: Régime Diabolique products are physical print books?

Tags: all-for-one

For the *[All for One: Régime Diabolique](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/4702/all-for-one-regime-diabolique)* line the only books physically in print are *All for One: Régime Diabolique* core rule book and *All For One: Paris Gothique*. Everything else is electronic/PDF. Is that correct?

Comment: I was about to go consult RPGGeek to see if it had the answer, but I see you've already done that. :)

Comment: Yes, which was misleading as some of the PDFs seem to have ISBN #s.

Comment: ISBNs can be used for digital books, so unfortunately the presence of an ISBN doesn't give any clues about whether there is a print version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time TAG have produced print copies of the following books:

- *All for One: Regime Diabolique*
- *Paris Gothique*
- *Le Mousqetaire Deshonore*
- *Richelieu's Guide Compendium 1*

These books are available in print or PDF. (The Richelieu's Guide Compendium is not available as a PDF at this time.)

Triple Ace Games released approximately 1 PDF title per month for the game line during the first 2 years of production, typically a *Richelieu's Guide to Something* as a 12-16 page PDF. The first 8 of these have been compiled as a print volume, with subsequent compiled volumes to follow. They also kept up a steady pace with the numbered adventure scenarios, the single installment *Force Majeure*, being the first, and the 4 installment *Le Mousqetaire Deshonore* coming out steadily afterward. This 4-part adventure series was then released as a print compilation. Numerous free 4-6 page pdf releases were also made available.

The line was later introduced as a Savage Worlds setting, with its core setting book in print.

Answer (score 4):

Le Mousquetaire Deshonore has been released in print.

http://www.gameslore.com/acatalog/PR_All_For_One_Le_Mousquetaire_Deshonore.html

I'm hopeful they'll combine the assorted Richelieu's Guides into one or 2 volumes.